# Intuitive picture for topological and fractal dimensions of a fractal

Tags: general-topology, fractals

The usual one-liner definition given for what a fractal dimension represents, is along the lines of: *a measure of the change in complexity of the fractal pattern at different scales of measurement.*

On the other hand, for the topological dimension of a fractal, it is often described as a union of open covers/sets that contain the topological space in which the fractal lies.

These two definitions are both very vague and confusing to me, likely because I sadly lack a good understanding of topology in general, but I was hoping maybe someone can elucidate the meaning behind these two quantities with simple examples of fractals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple definitions (not always equivalent) of topological dimension and of whatever you mean by "fractal dimension". Let's stick to metric spaces, without going to general topological spaces.

#### Topological dimension

The inductive definition of topological dimension says: the space is $0$-dimensional if it can be covered by arbitrarily small open subsets with empty boundary. For example, the middle-third Cantor set qualifies because it can be covered by $2^n$ intervals, each of size $3^{-n}$ (as small as we wish), and each of them has empty boundary (is both open and closed).  Two more observations:

- a finite metric space is $0$ dimensional (just cover it by one-point subsets);
- a connected metric space is not $0$-dimensional (unless it's one point): there is no way to write it as the union of disjoint open sets, by the very definition of "connected".

Then, a space is $1$-dimensional if it's not $0$-dimensional but can be covered by arbitrarily small open subsets with $0$-dimensional boundary. The von Koch snowflake (or any simple curve for that matter) is $1$-dimensional: on one hand, it's connected, so cannot be $0$-dimensional; on another, it can be covered by tiny subarcs, whose boundary has $2$ points, so is $0$-dimensional.  Two more examples:

- Cartesian product of the Cantor set with a line segment is $1$-dimensional.
- The Sierpinski carpet is $1$-dimensional: cut it into small pieces with $0$-dimensional boundary by using vertical and horizontal lines that pass through centers of removed squares.

The topological dimension is always an integer, by definition. So it neglects a good deal of information about the fractal structure; there is no difference between a line segment and a snowflake curve.

#### Hausdorff/Minkowski/box/packing dimensions, whatever you call them

Ignoring the details which are responsible for the variety of names, let's say that a $d$-dimensional metric space is one where we need about $\epsilon^{-d}$ sets of size $\epsilon$ to cover it, when $\epsilon$ is small. So, a square is two-dimensional: use an $n\times n$ grid of smaller squares, with $\sqrt{2}/n \le \epsilon$. The Cantor set has $d=\log 2/\log 3 $ because we need $2^n$ subsets of size $3^{-n}$, so choosing $n$ so that $3^{-n}<\epsilon$ yields about $\epsilon^{-d}$ sets. The Sierpinski carpet requires $8^n$ smaller squares of size $3^{-n}$, so its dimension works out to $\log 8/\log 3$, between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider any Cube $Q\subset\mathbb R^d$ with edges of length $c$ Then 
denote by $2Q$ the corresponding cube obtain by doubling all edges of $Q$.

We not that $Vol(2Q) = 2^d vol(Q)$. in fact if $l*Q$ denote the cube obtained by multiplying all edges of $Q$ by $l$ then 
we have 
$vol(Q)= l^d vol(Q)$. This formula holds true also for euclidean balls and some oder nice geometric object. **See that the topology of $\mathbb R^d$ is completly defined cubes or Balls**

So intuitively a family of objects $(F_i)_i$ are called to be fractals of dimension $\alpha$ if there generate a topology in which the following holds true 
$$ vol(l*F_i) =l^\alpha vol(F_i).$$